# How to set properties from outside the widget?

Tags: flutter

I have variable `Width` in `widget 1` and I'm trying to embed `widget 1` inside `widget 2` and give it the `width` of `200` instead of `default value` of `35`. How to set `200`from `widget 2`? I tried to use a constructor `ToolSetRight({widthProperty}` to set it from outside but its not the correct way it seems.

**Widget1**

```
    double Width = 35;
    
    class ToolSetRight extends StatelessWidget {
      ToolSetRight({widthProperty}
Width = widthProperty 

);
```

**Widget2**

```
class _LandingState extends State<Landing> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  
  final pages = [
     
    ToolSetRight(widthProperty: 200)
    
  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a local property in the `FirstWidget` that receives a value from outside to store the received value from the `SecondWidget`, e.g. in the `FirstWidget` define a variable called `final double width;`, and make a constructor for the widget that accepts a value, and set it to the local property you have defined, e.g. `const FirstWidget({this.width = 35});` (the 35 I am using is just a default value in case you haven't passed a value from the second widget, so if you will always pass a value you can remove it), now you can use the local property inside your widget tree as you want. Inside the `SecondWidget`, when you use the `FirstWidget` you can pass the value to the widget from outside by the same way that Flutter works.

**Here is a complete code snippet for the two widgets:**

```
// First Widget:

class FirstWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;

  const FirstWidget({this.width = 35});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: width,
    );
  }
}

// Second Widget:

class SecondWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FirstWidget(
      width: 200,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the default width in case the passed width is null, if the passed value is not null, set passed the width

for example

```
class WidgetWithWidth extends StatelessWidget{
  final double width;
  final double defaultWidth = 35;
  const WidgetWithWidth({Key key, this.width}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: width ?? defaultWidth,
    );
  }
  
}
```

So in case the parent widget passed the width, it will use it, if the the parent widget didn't pass the width, the child widget will use the default width